# Update CSV header Using CsvReader

Tags: c#, stream, streamreader

I have a CSV file that I grab & convert it into Stream. I need a way to modify header without converting stream to string. Is there a way around?

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
//need to update stream here & continue with the CSV reader
using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(resStream), true))
{
//other code
}
```

Comment: Please be more clear: what "header" do you need to modify?

Comment: the first row (header row) of the CSV file

Comment: Also, please say which "CsvReader" class this is. There is no such class in .NET.

Comment: This is where I got it from:http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Derive your own class from StreamReader and override the function you use for reading it, inserting the proper behavior.